# Hide a .NET MessageBox' Taskbar Icon

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox

Is it possible to call the static `MessageBox` class `Show()` method in a way that it does not have a taskbar icon, or has a custom image?  I'm trying to find an alternative to constructing  custom `MessageBox` class.

Thanks.

I tried to the the `DefaultDesktopOnly` option in the following way:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you would like to do something?", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

However there was still an icon in the taskbar and also the main form started crashing as well.  I'm in Win7 if it matters.  Are there stability issues with `DefaultDesktopOnly`?

Comment: Would MessageBoxIcon.None be a viable option? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @OnoSendai Unfortunately that only sets the icon in the actual messagebox.

Comment: I faced a similar problem a short while ago and creating my own custom class turned out to be a lot less difficult than customizing the MessageBox class...

Comment: @Arie Yeah that is what I figured would probably be the case.  I thought I would take one last try with all the hotshots on SO.

Comment: @kmarks2 is there something wrong with Alejandro's answer? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Dialecticus I think it probably would have, but I had long since built my own MessageBox, which had the benefit of also letting me tweak some other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.

MessageBox functionality is given to us as is. Some items are configurable, some are not. There are alternatives on the net. Check out in CodeProject, they have a few.

Comment: While it's true that the MessageBox is "as-is" without possibility of further customization beyond the given options, this particular case IS possible, by just giving it an owner.

Comment: Yeah, being sealed and static this is what I figured.  It was a long shot, but I thought I'd ask.  Yeah I already built a substitute that works fine.

Answer (score 9):

You need to give the `MessageBox` an owner window that has (or not) an icon of itself for the dialog to NOT to show on its own. If you call the `MessageBox` from an open form, you can pass the form as the first parameter to make it its owner:

```
// Assume "this" is a form, not valid from any other class
if (MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you would like to do something?", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

But if your program has no other GUI visible at the moment, you may simply create a dummy form just for the sake of providing it an owner, like so:

```
// A new, invisible form is created as the MessageBox owner, this prevents it from appearing in the taskbar
if (MessageBox.Show(new Form(), "Are you sure you would like to do something?", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the MessageBoxOptions enum

```
MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly
```

Comment: Are you sure [it's the option he's looking for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) (BTW it's kind of side effect of that option but it's not made for that and it'll carry many other drawbacks). Is it what he wants?

Comment: I cannot provide an alternative at this time, but this does work, will look at alternatives